# Deleting a git repo of home directory on mac

Tags: git, macos, terminal

[image: Every time I log into terminal on my Mac this is what happens]
I would like it to have a fresh window each time I open terminal and can't figure out how to delete this repo. When I enter pwd to find the folder path it just says user/tannerlarson but I can't find it... Thinking its the entire home directory not sure what happened. 
[image: This is my home folder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the git repo, you need to remove the whole `.git` directory, because the system will hide all directories started with `.`, you can only see it when you 

`ls -la`

when you see it's there

`rm -rf .git`

**WARNING**: Make sure you copy the full command, since `rm -rf .` will remove everything under your home directory.